# missing attribute

Tags: java, html, jsoup

ok so im using Jsoup to get the link for an image from this piece of code

```
<div id="section_1" class="story  inview" bgimage="AAA" style="width: 1366px; height: 853.75px; background-image: url(http://Fake.link.comm);" scrollto="0">
```

and the code that i'm using is this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(web).get();
Element content = doc.getElementById("section_1");
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass(content.className());
for( Element e : elements ) {
          String attr = e.attr("style");
          System.out.println( attr.substring( attr.indexOf("http://"), attr.indexOf(")") ) );
        }
```

however it gives me back an out of index error with -1 value after some looking into it i realized
for some reason the code that the parser reads is this

```
<div id="section_1" class="story" bgimage="AAA">
```

and as such there is no "style" attribute.... can someone tell me why it is behaving like this? many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have used `content` instead of `e` it would have worked.

```
      String attr = content.attr("style");
      System.out.println( attr.substring( attr.indexOf("http://"), attr.indexOf(")") ) );
```

You just found some other `div` in `e`.